# How to spread a workbook to set of worksheets of another workbook use openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to spread a worksheet to set of worksheets of another workbook use openpyxl. My code is this

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# creat a empty workbook
wb = openpyxl.workbook()
# creat the source workbook file
fileS = open('path to source file', 'rb')
wbS = load_workbook(filename=fileS)
o=0
d={}
for i in range(1,31)
    k = 2
    # creat a holder to contains the worksheet objects
    d['ws{:d}'.format(i)] = wb.create_sheet('{:d}day'.format(i))
    # d[i] is the ith worksheet of the created  new workbook
    # but the d[i] is not correctly
    d[i]['B%d'%k] = wbS['B%d'%o].value
    o = o + 7
wb.save('path and filename to created files')
```

How do I use a structure to express very  worksheet of the created new worksheet.I used a dictory but it show invalid syntax.